# Dispatch action N times but only make one API call in effect and combine result N times

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have multiple instances of a the same component in an Angular application. Each instance of the component will dispatch an action `[Action] LoadData` to load data from an external API. The payload of the action has information about which component who dispatched the action, to be able to store it in the correct corresponding place in the `store`.

The fetched data will be the same each time, no matter what other payload is included in the action. Since this is the case, there's no need for me to do multiple API calls to load the same data, so I can cancel out any previous unfinished calls with `switchMap`.

For this I have two effects, one to load the data:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
loadData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoadData>(LOAD_DATA),
    switchMap((action) => { // This will cancel out any previous service call
        return this.service.loadData().pipe(
            tap(val => {
                console.log(`Loading data...`)
                this.dataSubject$.next(val) // When the data is fetched, emit on the subject
            })
        );
    })
);
```

and one to handle the dispatched action combined with the data

```
@Effect()
handleActionAndDataLoaded$ = combineLatest(
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<LoadData>(LOAD_DATA)
    ),
    this.dataSubject$.asObservable()
).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log(`All done`))
)
```

and where `dataSubject$` is a `Subject`.

This is where the tricky part for me comes in. I need the second effect to be triggered `n` times if the `LoadData` action has been dispatched `n` times and then handle the data in combination with other action payloads accordingly. What I now instead get is one trigger of the second effect.

Reading into `combineLatest` and looking at marble diagrams, this is of course the expected behaviour.

Represented in marble diagrams I get something like

[image]

What I would need is instead something like below.

[image]

I know there are other ways of solving the whole issue by changing other things in the architecture of the application, but this is what I have to work with at the moment, and it seems to me like an interesting `rxjs` question!

How can this be achieved? What combination of operators am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this is easiest solved inside your actual service. Just apply a caching subject in there and return that to your effect. Call only gets done once, and your other requirements are met.

Comment: How are u knowing that `n` events are over ? Can it be re triggered again in the app ? Otherwise, you'll end up losing any changes in response of `this.service.loadData()` when the new set of event is triggered. If possible please elaborate more

Comment: @ShashankVivek good question! In my real code they will be dispatched once in batch and some other times, though not very frequently. Also, maximum of `n = 12.`

Comment: @DanielB: IMHO, you are not doing it properly. Using `RxJs` to handle this issue wont be a good practice. Seems more like a cover-up.  As far as I remember, the `switchMap` switches the value with internal `Observable` , not sure about the comment where you are expecting previous `http` call to get canceled. `1.` To confirm, I think your `LOAD_DATA` would be making 12 API call (i.e. for every event of action) `2.` If you are open, I can try to answer without Rxjs but with better `effect` and `action` management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it should look more similar to the first diagram:

```
actions -1-2-3-----------
data    ---------B-------
result  ---------(1B2B3B)
```

Otherwise it looks like you expect LoadData actions to be paired with previously fetched data.

You can create a state machine using merge and scan:

```
const createEffectWithScan = (actions$: Observable<string>, subject$: Observable<string>) =>
  merge(
    actions$.pipe(map(x => ({ type: 'action', value: x }))),
    subject$.pipe(map(x => ({ type: 'data', value: x }))),
  ).pipe(
    scan(
      (a, b) => b.type === 'action'
        ? { data: null, toEmit: [], buffer: [...a.buffer, b.value] }
        : { data: b.value, toEmit: a.buffer, buffer: []  }
      , { data: null, buffer: [], toEmit: [] }
    ),
    filter(x => x.data !== null),
    concatMap(x => x.toEmit.map(a => a + x.data))
  );
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing-a7s32v?file=src%2Feffect.spec.ts)

As you've mentioned, this is a nice exercise, but should probably be solved another way. Poking values imperatively via subjects is not a good solution.

Comment: This is great, thank you @NickL! And superb example with the spec-tests aswell! I often find myself in the situation of reflecting over what rxjs operators to use for what case, and I'd totally forgotten about `scan`. 

I will refactor the code to be able to implement it in a better way, but I appreciate the challenge and exercise of doing it the reactive way as well!